# deploy angular front end and nodejs back end in same project to (linux) azure app service

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, express

I have a project with angular (front end) and a server.js file to serve the backend but I can't seem to get the server to run in Azure.  The angular app runs just fine but I can't get the server up.  The layout is like this:

```
my-app
 src
   -app
   -assets
   -environments
 server.js
```

So, basically the angular and server.js are one project.  No separation with frontend or backend.  I imagine that I need to do something with the server.js and package.json file in order for this to work but am not sure.  Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Listen on a specific port via the PORT environment variable
let port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.static("/home/site/wwwroot"));

let proxy = cors_proxy.createServer({
    originWhitelist: [], // Allow all origins
    requireHeaders: [], // Do not require any headers.
    removeHeaders: [], // Do not remove any headers.
});

let request = require('request');

app.use(cors());

app.get("/api/users", (req, res) => {
    const options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'scim api',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/scim-json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '
    }
};
const response = request(options, function(error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);

    res.send(response.body);
})

})

app.delete("/api/users/:id", (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;

const options = {
    'method': 'DELETE',
    'url': `scim api`,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/scim-json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '
    }
};
const response = request(options, function(error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
})
 res.send(response);
})

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
   res.sendFile("/home/site/wwwroot/index.html")
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve | node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
 },
```

How can I get my backend server.js to run within azure app service?  I am doing a straight deploy from vscode to Azure.  Not sure why the server will not deploy.  I am building the dist files and then deploying to Azure.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks [@Bhargav Bachina](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/two-ways-to-deploy-angular-with-nodejs-backend-on-azure-app-services-68f149522006) for the clear steps.

AFAIK, the problem here is with the Start script.

In your **`package.json`**,  modify the `start script` as below.

```js
"start": "ng serve & node server.js",
```

As we want to run both `front` and `backend` servers in same project, we need to use `&` symbol.

- Create Azure Linux App Service in Azure Portal and select the run time stack as Node.

[image]

- Make sure your `server.js` file is in the Application root directory.
- In `Azure Portal` => `Your App Service` => `Configuration` => `General Settings`, add the below `Startup command`.

```js
npm start
```

[image]

This ensures to run the `start script` which we have mentioned in `package.json`, when the deployed Application gets started.

- Also add the Application setting `PORT`  with value `80` in the `Application Settings` Configuration section.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but now I am getting this: :( Application Error when setting the startup command to npm start instead of npx serve -s.  When I use npx serve -s I at least can see my app but when using npm start I just get an error page.  Any ideas of why this is happening? Also, when using npx serve -s my back end is not running.  I can only see the front end without any data loading.  I get a 200 but it never reaches the backend.